# Python: cTurtle with a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I need to make a function that does this. (Python 3.3 by the way)

> Write the contract, docstring, and implementation for a procedure plotEarthquakeData that takes two dates and plots all the earthquake data from USGS between the given dates with dots on the world map. You can use the procedure dot from the cTurtle library that takes the size and color. You can use the product of 4 and the magnitude for the size of dots while using the depth for the right color. The procedure bgpic is useful to put the world map image in the background while the procedure setWorldCoordinates can help you plot the dots more easily.
>   Assume the entire map shows -180 to 180 degrees from left to right and -90 to 90 degrees from bottom to top.

[plotEarthquakeData("2013/06/01", "2013/06/04") should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5doD.png)

I have this so far.  Underneath it are functions I've already written that will be used in the plotEarthquakeData function as well.

```
import cTurtle

def plotEarthquakeData(date1,date2):
    """ takes two dates and plots all the earthquake data from USGS between the
    given dates with dots on the world map."""
    myTurtle = cTurtle.Turtle()
    myTurtle.bgpic('map.gif')
    myTurtle.setWorldCoordinates(-180,-90,180,90)
    data = parseEarthquakeData(date1,date2)
    for i in range (len(data[1])):
        myTurtle.goto(data[0][i], data[1][i])
        myturtle.dot(4*data[2][i],colorCode(data[3][1]))
```

-

```
def colorCode(depth):
    """takes the depth of an earthquake and returns the corresponding color for
    the earthquake."""
    if depth<=33:
        return "orange"
    elif depth<=70:
        return "yellow"
    elif depth <=150:
        return "green"
    elif depth<=300:
        return "blue"
    elif depth <=500:
        return "purple"
    else:
        return "red"
```

-

```
import urllib.request
def parseEarthquakeData(date1, date2):
    dataFile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://neic.usgs.gov/neis/gis/qed.asc")
    latList = []
    longList = []
    magList = []
    depthList = []
    count =0
    for aline in dataFile:
        aline = aline.decode('ascii')
        splitData = aline.split(',')
        count = count+1
        if count>=2:

            if (betweenDates (splitData[0],date1,date2)):
                latList.append(splitData[2])
                longList.append(splitData[3])
                magList.append(splitData[4])
                depthList.append(splitData[5])
    finalList=[]
    finalList.append(latList)
    finalList.append(longList)
    finalList.append(magList)
    finalList.append(depthList)
    return finalList
```

When i try to run plotEarthquakeData i get this error, which i don't know what to make of.

```
plotEarthquakeData("2013/06/01","2013/06/04")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    plotEarthquakeData("2013/06/01","2013/06/04")
  File "C:\Python33\plotEarthquakes.py", line 89, in plotEarthquakeData
    myTurtle.goto(data[0][i], data[1][i])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cTurtle.py", line 1295, in setpos
    self._goto(_Vec(pos, y))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cTurtle.py", line 2255, in _goto
    diff = end-start
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cTurtle.py", line 274, in __sub__
    return _Vec(self[0]-other[0], self[1]-other[1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

so any help to try and get me to understand where i'm going wrong will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`latlist` and `longlist` contains a string, not a number, since `splitData` is a string.

You'll have to convert them to floats if you want to do that:

```
if (betweenDates (splitData[0],date1,date2)):
    latList.append(float(splitData[2]))
    longList.append(float(splitData[3]))
```

I expect the other variables to be floats too, no?

```
    magList.append(float(splitData[4]))
    depthList.append(float(splitData[5]))
```

Hope this helps!